# how to pass argument to postDelay() inside FOR loop

Tags: android, sms, postdelayed

I want to introduce the function postDelayed() inside my FOR loop but the compiler no longer recognizes the following variables:
Jarray,
i,
getString()

```
...
JSONObject result1 = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = result1.getJSONArray("doc");

            for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {


                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        int length = message.length();

                        if (length > MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
                            ArrayList<String> messagelist = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
                            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage("+3311111111", null, messagelist, null, null);
                        } else {
                            smsManager.sendTextMessage("+331111111", null, message, null, null);
                        }


                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); //here 3 errors: error: local variable jArray is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final / error: unreported exception JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown / error: local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

...

                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Envoi du doc " + json_data.getString("doc_title"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // here, error: unreported exception JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                    }
                }, 30000);

            }
```

thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1**

Can't use a final variable in a loop. You can do it like below

```
for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    final int index = i;
```

Now use `index` wherever you need to use `i`.

**Issue 2**

Any variable that you access inside an inner class/anonymous class needs to be final. So, `jArray` needs to be final like this.

```
final JSONArray jArray = result1.getJSONArray("doc");
```

**Issue 3**

When you are doing any JSON operation you need to handle the exceptions like this

```
try{
    // Do your operation here like 
    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
catch(JSONException jse){
    jse.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but I have this error message: error: cannot assign a value to final variable i (i++)
and "getString" : Unhandled exception : org.json.JSONException

Comment: You can when you are declaring. You can't modify it later.

Comment: I need the _incremented_ variable "i" to go through my loop.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: my loop its in my TRY
i have catch error:
try{
JSONObject result1 = new JSONObject(result);
            final JSONArray jArray = result1.getJSONArray("doc");
int i;
            for (i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {...}
} catch (
                JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

        }

with that i have this error: error: local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Comment: this loop its in class BgTask extends AsyncTask, not in activity class.
i declared it in top of main and always same error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't what I was thinking. That was my mistake. Try now.

Comment: Thank's now i have 1 error in line : JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(index);

error: unreported exception JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: put try-catch for this